# roxy conversion to ml-gradle properties error

Tags: marklogic, ml-gradle, roxy

Trying to convert an existing roxy project to ml-gradle using the ml-gradle plugin. Here's the build.gradle:

```
plugins {
   id "net.saliman.properties" version "1.5.1"
   id "com.marklogic.ml-gradle" version "3.1.0"
}
```

This generates following error:

```
> Task :mlRoxyMigrateProperties FAILED
  Mapping Roxy property 'group' to ml-gradle property 'mlGroupName'
  Mapping Roxy property 'user' to ml-gradle property 'mlUsername'
  Mapping Roxy property 'password' to ml-gradle property 'mlPassword'
  Mapping Roxy property 'app-name' to ml-gradle property 'mlAppName'
  Mapping Roxy property 'content-db' to ml-gradle property 'mlContentDatabaseName'
  Mapping Roxy property 'modules-db' to ml-gradle property 'mlModulesDatabaseName'
  Mapping Roxy property 'content-forests-per-host' to ml-gradle property 'mlContentForestsPerHost'
  Mapping Roxy property 'app-port' to ml-gradle property 'mlRestPort'
  Mapping Roxy property 'authentication-method' to ml-gradle property 'mlRestAuthentication'
  Mapping Roxy property 'appuser-password' to ml-gradle property 'mlRestAdminPassword'
  Mapping Roxy property 'test-port' to ml-gradle property 'mlTestRestPort'

  FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

  * What went wrong:
   Execution failed for task ':mlRoxyMigrateProperties'.
  > Could not get unknown property 'roxyProperties' for task ':mlRoxyMigrateProperties' of type com.marklogic.gradle.task.roxy.RoxyMigratePropertiesTask.
```

Nothing is written to gradle.properties so it failed to copy over any property at all. Any suggestions to make it go past this error ? Thanks

Comment: what command did you execute? Have you set a project property specifying the path to the `roxyProjectPath`? i.e. `gradle mlRoxyMigrateProperties -ProxyProjectPath=/path/to/roxy/project`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade to 3.2.2 or higher - you're hitting a bug fixed in 3.2.2.